# Select DOM within Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a bit problem with my jQuery, I need to select a class within 'variable-scope' element.. i don't know how to describe in simple term.. but here's my case

i got this structure element:

```
<div class="alpha">
  <div class="bravo">
          Testing
  </div>
</div>
```

i use variable to 'scope' :

```
var theData=jQuery(".alpha");
```

My Question is how to select class "bravo" in theData variable ?

Thanks

Comment: Many answers to this question use .find() instead of .children(). The latter is faster since it only access direct children of an element. You can also use a selector like: `theData.children('.bravo');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery) with `".bravo"` selector as first parameter, `theData` as second parameter to set `context` of `jQuery()` call to `theData` jQuery object

```js
var theData = jQuery(".alpha");
var bravo = jQuery(".bravo", theData);
bravo.css("color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="alpha">
  <div class="bravo">
    Testing
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will return from child elements

```
theData.find('.bravo')
```

```js
var theData=jQuery(".alpha");
var bravo = theData.find('.bravo');
console.log( bravo.text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alpha">
  <div class="bravo">
          Testing
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you want to do `find`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
var theData = jQuery(".alpha");
var bravo = theData.find(".bravo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var theData = jQuery(".alpha").find(".bravo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [**`children()`**](https://api.jquery.com/children/) function

```
var theData=jQuery(".alpha");
var bravo=theData.children('.bravo')
```

```js
    console.log(bravo.text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alpha">
  <div class="bravo">
          Testing
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var theData=jQuery(".alpha");
var bravo=theData.children('.bravo')
```